# How can I compare two lists (containing character and number in it) in tcl?

Tags: list, tcl

I have two lists called `hga` and `bbb`. I am using `tcl` from a software called `VMD`. Now I would like to compare these lists by finding the common residues and different residues in these lists. How can I do that?

```
% set hga [atomselect 0 "name CA and within 8 of resname HEM"]
% set bbb [atomselect 1 "name CA and within 8 of resname HEM"]
% $hga get {resname resid}
% $bbb get {resname resid}
```

`resname` part is character and `resid` part is a number.

---

UPDATE : using `package require struct` gives me error. And I am not the root user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195153/what-is-the-right-way-of-comparing-two-lists-in-tcl

Comment: You can use [::struct::list](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.html#1) maybe (after using `package require struct`) to get the common items and then define your own proc for the ones that are different. I'm not going to write if for you because you haven't shown any attempt at the problem itself, but hopefully that can help you get started.

Comment: using `package require struct` gives me error. And I am not the root user.

Comment: You should be able to install the package as a normal user beneath your home directory (using a [from-source distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcllib/files/tcllib/1.16/) instead of one done by some redistributor). You can then tell Tcl where it is via the [TCLLIBPATH](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1787) environment variable IIRC.

Comment: @DonalFellows : I will do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have VMD so I made proc from example output.  This script finds indexes with the same attribute value. You need to set the attributes and use them in your get. Example:

```
set attrs {name backbone}
set values [$sel get $attrs]
set answer [same_values $attrs $values]
```

Test script

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

# http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.7/ug/node181.html
# $sel get {attr1 attr2}
# is a list of sublists. {attr1 attr2} {attr1 attr2} ...

set attrs {name backbone}
set values "{N 1} {H 0} {CA 1} {CB 0} {C 1} {O 1}"

proc same_values {attrs values} {
    set len [llength $values]
    set "matches(_ATTRIBUTE VALUE)" INDEXES
    set attrs_length [llength $attrs]

    for {set i 0} {$i < $len} {incr i} {
        set item_a [lindex $values $i]
        set search_indexes [list]

        for {set k 0} {$k < $attrs_length} {incr k} {
            set key [list [lindex $attrs $k] [lindex $item_a $k]]
            if {![info exists "matches($key)"]} {
                # value hasn't been indexed.
                # create index list and add to search list
                set "matches($key)" [list $i]
                lappend search_indexes $k
            }
        }

        # continue if we don't have anything to search
        if {[llength $search_indexes] == 0} {continue}

        # search the rest of the list for matches
        for {set j [expr $i + 1]} {$j < $len} {incr j} {
            set item_b [lindex $values $j]

            foreach {k} $search_indexes {
                set a [lindex $item_a $k]
                set b [lindex $item_b $k]
                set attr [lindex $attrs $k]

                if {$a == $b} {
                    set key [list $attr $a]
                    lappend "matches($key)" $j
                }
            }
        }
    }

    set result [list]
    set keys [lsort [array names matches]]

    foreach {key} $keys {
        lappend result $key "$matches($key)"
    }

    return $result
}

set answer [same_values $attrs $values]

foreach {attr_value indexes} $answer {
    puts "$attr_value = $indexes"
}
```

output:

```
% ./test.tcl
_ATTRIBUTE VALUE = INDEXES
backbone 0 = 1 3
backbone 1 = 0 2 4 5
name C = 4
name CA = 2
name CB = 3
name H = 1
name N = 0
name O = 5
```

Comment: by common elements I meant residues. But thats fine.