# tcl remove redundant items from list

Tags: list, tcl, duplicates

I'm new to tcl and I want to remove redundant items from a list of pairs. Here's sample list

```
  set example_list {{1 0} {0 1} {1 4} {3 5} {6 7} {4 1} {2 1} {1 5} {5 3}}
```

I would like to return the list.

{{1 0} {1 4} {3 5} {6 7} {2 1} {1 5}}

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197725/1578604) for `lequal` comparator:

```
proc lequal {l1 l2} {
    foreach elem $l1 {
        if {$elem ni $l2} {return 1}
    }
    foreach elem $l2 {
        if {$elem ni $l1} {return 1}
    }
    return 0
}

set l [list [lindex $example_list 0]]
foreach elem1 $example_list {
    set found 0
    foreach elem2 $l {
        if { [lequal $elem1 $elem2] == 0 } {
            set found 1
            break
        }
    }
    if { $found == 0 } {
        lappend l $elem1
    }
}
```

Comment: This outputs: {5 3} {1 5} {2 1} {4 1} {6 7} {3 5} {1 4} {0 1}, but I also want to remove other repeated elements like one of {5 3} or {5 3}

Comment: @SarahKempka I've changed the approach, this should work _exactly_ as you need (preserving the order of the original list)

Answer (score 1):

With Tcl 8.6, you can do this:

```
set pairs [lsort -unique [lmap l $example_list {lsort -integer $l}]]
```

It uses `lmap` to apply an integer `lsort` to each pair, so duplicate pairs get the same string representation, then `lsort -unique` to remove the duplicates (though with reordering; hope that doesn't matter).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. Especially about `lmap` command.